# How to check if an element in an array is in another array? (nested for loops)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

This definitely isn't the best way to do this validation, but this method will have to do.

The below code will return false even when I have a valid hex input to the textArea, such as 4A, 3B, etc.

Any help much appreciated!

```
        var userCode = [];
        // Code below parses all of the data to one long string with no spaces in upper case.
        var userCodeInput = document.getElementById("taProgramInput").value.split(" ").join("").toString().toUpperCase();
        var hexChar = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
        var validHex;
        // Populate the userCode array by looping through the userCodeInput's length.
        for (i = 0; i < userCodeInput.length; i++) {
            userCode[i] = userCodeInput[i];
        }
        // Compare each element of the userCode array with each valid hex character.
        for (j = 0; j < hexChar.length; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < userCode.length; k++) {
                if (hexChar[j] !== userCode[k]) {
                    validHex = false;
                    break;
                } else {
                    validHex = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (validHex === false) {
            _StdOut.putText("Invalid hex, valid hex characters include A-F and/or 0-9");
        } else {
            // Accepted command
            _StdOut.putText("Valid Hex")
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `indexOf`:

```
let validHex = true;
for (let k = 0; k < userCode.length; k++) {
    if (hexChar.indexOf(userCode[k]) === -1) {
        validHex = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

You can also try to convert your hex string to an int:

```
let validHex = parseInt(userCodeInput, 16) !== NaN;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a neat function that can do this check for you:

```
function isHex(userCode) {
   var paresedUserCode = parseInt(userCode, 16);
   return (paresedUserCode.toString(16) === userCode.toLowerCase())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've made this more complicated then it has to be.
You could replace all the non hex characters from the user's input and check if the resulting string has the same length as the original string.

Here is an example:

```js
function validHex(value){
  var onlyHex = value.toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-F0-9]/g, "");
  return onlyHex.length == value.length;
}

checkBtn.onclick = function(){
  console.log(validHex(hexInput.value));
}
```

```html
<textarea id="hexInput"></textarea>
<br>
<button id="checkBtn">Check</button>
```

This is probably not that efficient but it requires less code and it is easier to understand.

If instead you want to go with the arrays approach you could loop through each character in the user input string and check if any of those characters is not an accepted hex character.

Here is an example:

```
var hexArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
var userInput = ....; 
var validHex = userInput.length;// initially 'true' if the user has inputed something.
for(var i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++){
    if(hexArray.indexOf(userInput[i]) == -1){ // not hex
        validHex = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseInt` function with second parameter with specifies the number system (it's numeric value, so `16` will stand for hexadecimal).
As I don't see the point in first loop (which populates the array userCode), I'll work with only one loop here, but you should still get the point here.

```
var validHex = true;
for (var i = 0; i < userCodeInput.length; i++) {
     if (!isValidHex(userCodeInput[i])) validHex = false;
}

function isValidHex(char) {
    var decoded  = parseInt(char, 16);
    if (char.toString() === decoded.toString()) return true;
    return false;
}
```

it should do the work here. Or you can take the regex approach here:

```
function isValidHex(char) {
    return /^[0-9A-F]+$/g.test(char);
}
```